# Как добавить масштабирование изображению которое на фоне страницы?

Tags: html

Добавил изображение на фон страницы по ссылке, но картинка слишком большая. Как сделать так, чтобы она масштабировалась под окно браузера и не растягивалась, а просто меняла размер?

```
body {
       background: url('http://i.imgur.com/DhrzPPd.jpg'); 
     }
```

Comment: в чем отличие растягивания от изменения размера? в чем отличие масштабирования от растягивания?

Comment: Чтобы картинка не растягивалась по окно браузера, а как бы меняла масштаб, как при зажатой клавише Shift в Word

Comment: Сложно понять о чем речь, но думаю поможет: background: url('http://i.imgur.com/DhrzPPd.jpg') 50% 50% / cover no-repeat;

Comment: @Fanning таки мне интересно чем отличается растягивание от масштабирования? это принципиально ортогональные вещи?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, думается в данном контексте "масштабирование" - изменение размеров сохраняя пропорции, "растягивание" изменение размеров без сохранения пропорций.

Comment: @MedvedevDev спасибо, то что нужно.

Answer (score -1):

```
body {
background-image: url(images.jpg);/*Ссылка на вашу картинку*/
background-repeat: no-repeat;/*Запрещаем повторение картинки*/
background-size: cover; /* Масштабируем фон */
}
```